# When removing a group from a contact I get: Error - DB Constraint Violation - GroupContact, get API

Tags: upgrade, database, groups

[copied from https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20711
noted on CiviCRM version 4.7.27]

In the Contact record, when I try to remove or delete a contact from a group they've already been added to, I receive this error:

DB Constraint Violation - group_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for GroupContact,get API. If so, please raise a bug report.

I am able to remove a contact from a group when in the Group's list of contacts view, so this isn't critical. Posting in case it happens for others.

Answer (score 1):

This bug seems to occur on old (i.e. version 2.x) installations, due to an error in an old upgrade script that removed the location_id field from the civicrm_group_contact table.

You can fix it using this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_group_contact ADD COLUMN `location_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional location to associate with this membership'
```

Credit for the solution goes to Eileen, via this commit:

https://github.com/wikimedia/wikimedia-fundraising-crm/commit/e5b853cd55ebf83b68a783a86bf3274dcf20dfb9

Credit for the original issue linked in the question above goes to Lizz Trudeau.